# Scroll design for off the shelf tangential/cross flow fan rotor

Tags: airflow, aerodynamics, fan

I'm trying to figure out a somewhat optimized fan scroll shape for a cross flow fan rotor I aquired. However I seem to have vastly underestimated the complexity as I have a lot of trouble finding useful literature or other resources. The rotor in question is 240mm long and 60mm in diameter. It will be driven at a variable speed from 0-4000 rpm.
I'm thankful for any pointers in the right direction.
I can give other parameters such as blade angle and blade count if needed.

[image: Fan]

Comment: Blade angle will be important, as well as which way the blades face. Have a look at centrifugal fans.

Answer (score 0):

If it is "off-the-shelf" then all the relevant parameters will have been decided.

Just by the rpm range you state, there will be an optimum, but poor overall, angle and design.

For such a wide range of rpm an adjustable angle may be considered - as used in variable turbochargers. But this is usually done with the stator blades